# Open a new window with a CSS Button

Tags: css

Can anyone tell me what code to use to make a CSS button open into a new window? I see that the code to do this for a hyperlink on my site is: `target="_blank"`. But, I can't figure out how to use this code in conjunction with a CSS button? The code for my CSS button is:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
[button-link url="http://survey.constantcontact.com/survey/a07eaydg1tyi98r263b/a0114ieuk39a5/greeting"]
TAKE THE SURVEY HERE »
[/button-link]
</p>
```

Where would I insert the `target="_blank"` code in my CSS code to create the same "new window" effect that I'm able to create with a hyperlink?

Thank you, thank you!!!

Cassandra

Comment: why are you using a CSS Button instead of an anchor link?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do what you are trying to achieve. You can only really practically make "buttons" with either HTML form input elements or HTML anchor elements. Moreover, the `target=_blank` declaration to open a link in a new window applies only to the HTML anchor element and will not work on other things pretending to be anchors.

What you should be doing:

```
<p class="paragraph">
<a href="http://survey.constantcontact.com/survey/a07eaydg1tyi98r263b/a0114ieuk39a5/greeting" target="_blank">
TAKE THE SURVEY HERE »</a>
</p>
```

Here the `target=_blank` has been inserted into the anchor element and this solves your problem entirely.

You can then also apply the css styling to the `.paragraph` definition and the styling for the anchor to the anchor sub-part as such:

CSS:

```
.paragraph{
    text-align:center;
}
.paragraph a {
    font-color:#dd0000;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #000; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply... really, much appreciated. I can't understand why this isn't possible with a button, but thank you for the explanation and alternate options. -Cassandra

Comment: @Cassandra the simple solution is to make your anchor tag look like a button with CSS styling.

Answer (score 0):

try this.just copy,paste and run it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

 a{
  background-color: orange;
  border:3px outset black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;

 }

 a:focus{
  background-color: white;
 }




</style>

 <a href="#" tabindex="0" target="_blank"> TAKE THE SURVEY HERE » </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't expect anyone to take the time to write this code for me... really, much appreciated. Unfortunately, this code doesn't create the "button" effect that I'm looking for, which I guess is not possible. But, thank you for replying and helping!  -Cassandra

Comment: What type of a button do you expect. Put a image or link that you have seen

Answer (score 0):

I have made you a good button here : **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9zhdhof6/)**

```css
.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 28;
  -moz-border-radius: 28;
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="http://survey.constantcontact.com/survey/a07eaydg1tyi98r263b/a0114ieuk39a5/greeting" target="_blank">
TAKE THE SURVEY HERE »</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't expect anyone to spend the time to write this code for me... really, much appreciated. Unfortunately, this code doesn't create the "button" effect that I'm looking for. So, I guess it's not possible. That seams crazy to me. But, thank you for replying and helping!